# Какая оптимальная максимальная длина фамилий

Tags: html, тестирование

Верстаю сайт, заказчик упёрся в то, что вывод фамилии длиной более 16 символов выглядит некорректно.
Какая максимальная длина фамилий, которую нужно закладывать в вёрстку. Также подскажите какой-то ресурс с типовыми требованиями к тестированию.

Comment: Аудитория сайта - СНГ

Comment: лучше без ограничений. Фамилии разные бывают, не говоря уже про двойные

Comment: Таблица с данными, 5 столбцов, увы, вынужден экономить

Comment: не вижу связи между количеством столбцов и ограничением на длину

Comment: @Grundy, смею предположить, что у товарища место вширь сильно ограничено. Но тут что можно предложить - конечно же, уменьшить шрифт! поставить размер где-нибудь, например, 6-8 (с лупой можно прочитать), да еще плюс к этому - убрать всякие паддинги и прочее. А если убрать еще бордер, то места станет просто дофига)

Comment: @Keyl.in, а что значит _вывод фамилии длинной более 16 символов выглядит не корректно_?

Comment: @Grundy Начинает залазить под следующую колонку. Перенос строки работает как надо и спасает в случае если имена/фамилии не превышают длину в 16 симфолов

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9

вот список общерусских фамилий - можешь вогнать в excel и подсчитать сколько максимально символов для 90% фамилий (например), но как писали выше - есть и нерусские и двойные типа "череззаборногузадерищинский" - но 16 символов почти всегда за глаза хватит, всегда можно настроить css так, чтобы обрезать фамилии типа "череззаборногуз..."

Comment: @Zhihar Если ты считаешь это полноценным ответом - пиши в ответы пожалуйста вместо того что бы минусовать. Суть вопроса вот в чём: есть ли какие то стандарты, общепринятые в тесстировании, и какой то ресурс с "золотыми правилами", дабы я мог опелирывать аргументированно

Comment: Key.in я вообще никого никогда не минусую
касательно тестирования - твой сервис должен переваривать любое переданное кол-во символов, хоть тысячу, но выводить так, чтобы это не оказывало влияния на сайт. В присланной ссылке я тебе показал, что для корректного вывода подавляющего большинства русских (и скорее всего словянских) фамилий требуется ~12 символов. Если символов в фамилии больше - ее надо например обрезать и придумать способ если надо (например, навели мышкой) показать полностью

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Фамилии бывают разные.

Если сайту важна фамилия при вводе данных, то лучше совсем не ограничивать. Потому что если ограничить, то такие фамилии, к примеру, как:

```
Стародубский-Ромодановский
Михайловский-Данилевский
```

и прочие двойные фамилии будут в ущербе:)

Если же это не критично, то ограничить фамилию, как просит заказчик.

Если же это не input, а просто блоки, то можно прописать через стили

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
```

И задать подходящую длину для заказчика. Также можно уменьшать длину фамилии не троеточиями, а градиентным переходом в белый цвет через псевдоэлементы.

И  [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958/list-of-standard-lengths-for-database-fields)  соответственно

Comment: Понял, резонно, спасибо

Comment: Добавлю, что минимальная длина равна 1. Я лично знаю человека, живущего в России, у которого фамилия состоит из одной буквы. Подозреваю, что то же самое бывает и с именами.